# Can a semaphore be made out of just locks?

Tags: synchronization

I was wondering if a semaphore can be built using just locks. I've seen implementations with interrupt disable/enable and using atomic primitives like test&set, but is it possible to implement one using locks only?

It seems like doing something like

```
guard = 0;
...
while(test&set(guard));
```

is basically the same as doing a lock.acquire(). Am I missing anything here?

Edit: Part of the reason I'm asking this question is because I was reading these slides here: http://www.cs.washington.edu/homes/arvind/cs422/lectureNotes/l7-6.pdf These slides offer implementations of semaphores using interrupt disable and test&set, but poses the implementation of semaphores using locks as a question, which I took to imply that an implementation using locks might not work for some reason.

Comment: Can a lock be made out of only test-and-set?

Comment: A lock can definitely be made out of only test&set, but isn't that a converse problem? (Edit: Just to be clear, my question is that, even after knowing I can build semaphores with test&set, is there a reason I wouldn't be able to use locks instead?)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're busy-waiting in that loop.  What you call acquire() would be an operation that goes to sleep and is only woken up once the the semaphore has been acquired.